# Missing destination file operand Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command, line

I'm absolutely green in Linux command line and cannot get through this script:

```
read answer
case "$answer" in #starting a loop

1)
echo "Type the name of the script: "
read $a1
    while [ ! -f $a1 ]
    do
        echo "$a1 is not valid"
    read $a1
    done
    sudo cp -a $HOME/$a1 $HOME/$a1'backup'$(date "+_%d_%m_%Y")
    ;;
```

This gives me the following error:
cp: cannot copy a directory, '/home/ubuntu/', into itself, '/home/ubuntu/backup_13_12_2018/ubuntu'

What I'm trying to do is to create a copy of this script with a timestamp in the same directory.

Comment: Are you sure you ran this and copy-pasted correctly? The error seems impossible to happen as you describe.

Comment: I did run an older version I just noticed, thank you. Now the error is 'cannot copy a directory (...) into itself (...)

Comment: Include the full error message you get. It's an important piece in debugging. Replace the `(...)` with the exact text.

Comment: `read $a1` -- you're storing the read contents into the **value of the a1 variable** not in the variable itself: `read a1` is what you want.

Comment: You look like you're implementing a menu: investigate the shell `select` command which takes care of a lot of the grunt work for you.

Comment: cp: cannot copy a directory, '/home/ubuntu/', into itself, '/home/ubuntu/backup_13_12_2018/ubuntu'

Comment: It seems that it's trying to copy the whole directory instead of just the script

Comment: Please incorporate the mentioned changes into your script, run [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) on it, and if you're still having problems then update your question.